# Evitar actualizar pagina HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy manejando este código que me permite mostrar una imagen aleatoria cada vez que se visita mi página:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var totalCount = 20;
    function ChangeIt() 
    {
    var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
    document.body.background = 'bgimages/'+num+'.jpg';
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = '100% 100%';
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
    </body> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    ChangeIt();
    </script> 
    </html>
```

pero me di cuenta que al darle el botón de recarga de la página me vuelve a cambiar la imagen por una nueva aleatoria, lo cual básicamente es lógico, pero me gustaría saber si es posible evitar esto, es decir, que al darle refrescar pantalla permanezca la imagen que se eligió y que la unica forma de presentar una imagen nueva sea cerrando el navegador e ingresando nuevamente.

De antemano muchas gracias si me dan alguna idea de como hacerlo.

Comment: Tu pregunta se basa en opiniones, por lo que podría terminar cerrada. El problema se puede resolver de muchas formas, como por ejemplo, guardar el link de la imagen en una variable session o cookie, y leerla si es que está seteada y cargada

Comment: Solo con html no es posible. Con javascript podrias intentarlo con localStarage o sessionStorage... aqui hay algunos metodos posibles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus amables respuestas (Excorpion y masterguru). Eso ya me da una idea de por dónde buscar. Gracias!

Comment: Si lo consigues regresa y respondete a ti mismo, asi la comunidad lo sabra tambien. Luego, en unas 12 horas, podras aceptarte tu propia respuesta y asi no quedara pendiente eternamente.

Comment: Tendrías que utilizar localStorage que no se borra, ni tiene fecha de expiración, almacenar el nombre o ruta de imagen para que al recargar la página verifique si esta existe y la muestre. Si no existe sencillamente muestre otra y escriba el localStorage, y por javascript con el evento unload podrías eliminar el localStorage al cerrar el navegador. La segunda y creo mejor opción es utilizando sessionStorage, que funciona igual que localStorage pero persiste hasta cerrar el navegador, incluso si se refresca la página. Link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage